# How to check if the pendrive controller is okay?

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

I've bought Mach Xtreme ES SLC 32GB (USB 3.0) pendrive, specifically for portable Ubuntu installation (a real one, as on HDD, not LiveUSB made by Unetbootin etc). The pendrive seems perfectly fine - no bad sectors (checked with badsectors under Ubuntu and h2testw under Windows), speeds mostly match the declared ones and benchmarks, files are okay (filling the whole drive with them and copying them back => MD5 sums match), nothing looks wrong.

Until I boot Ubuntu from it. Then, it's a disaster.

No matter which filesystem I try (ext3, ext4, btrfs), either the OS fails to boot, with a grand amount of I/O errors reported on the device, or the OS boots in Recovery Mode, with no errors at all. Mounting the partitions under Ubuntu on my HDD works perfectly fine, fsck and btrfs check both report no errors at all - and basically I have no idea what might be wrong with it. Windows can access the pendrive perfectly well too (if it's formatted with FAT32/NTFS, of course).

Is there a way to check if it's a problem with the pendrive, or if there's a problem with OS booting from USB 3.0 pendrives? (I've had Ubuntu 13.10 installed on a 8GB USB 2.0 stick, which was perfectly fine.)

Comment: Could you give us some more info? Partition table, filesystem type, syslinux present, difference with respect to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch these instructions?

Comment: Regular DOS/MBR (as suggested by GParted), tried btrfs and ext4 with the same effect (installs fine, goes crazy once booted), GRUB installed as bootloader on pendrive w/o syslinux, and I want to install it like I would on a normal HDD, not a LiveUSB with persistence.

Comment: (Sorry for the delay, I had some serious problems with power and connectivity in my area since two days.)

Comment: Have you tried in a different computer ? I'm having similar issues wiht FreeNAS on one of my USB sticks so I'm about to try it in another computer.

Comment: I've tried in on 4 computers, with no luck. Normal usage - it's fine. Ubuntu booted - I/O errors.

Comment: FYI pen drives dont have "sectors"